# f2py error with allocatable arrays

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have a Fortran subroutine that I would like to use in Python.

```
subroutine create_hist(a, n, dr, bins, hist)
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real(8), intent(in) :: a(n)
    real(8), intent(in) :: dr
    integer, intent(out), allocatable :: hist(:)
    real(8), intent(out), allocatable :: bins(:)

    n_b = n_bins(a, n, dr)  ! a function calculating the number of bins
    allocate(bins(n_b+1))
    allocate(hist(n_b))
    hist = 0

    !... Create the histogram hist by putting elems of a into bins
end subroutine
```

It is a simple programme to get an array of numbers `a` and create a histogram based on given bin size `dr`. First, it gets the number of bins using function `n_bins` and then accordingly allocates the space for the arrays `bins` and `hist`.

While `gfortran` compiles this code fine, `f2py` raises an error:

```
/tmp/tmpY5badz/src.linux-x86_64-2.6/mat_ops-f2pywrappers2.f90:32.37:
      call create_hist_gnu(a, n, dr, bins, hist)
Error: Actual argument for 'bins' must be ALLOCATABLE at (1)
```

As I understand it, `f2py` does not tolerate allocating space for arrays at runtime (no idea why, as this seems to be a natural scientific need).

Could anyone please suggest a way to allocate Fortran arrays at run-time so that `f2py` is happy with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know f2py does not support dummy arguments (sometimes known as function parameters) which have the attribute `ALLOCATABLE`. An alternative would be to make it a large enough explicit shape array. You would then use just a certain part of the array.

```
subroutine create_hist(a, n, dr, n_b_max, bins, hist)
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real(8), intent(in) :: a(n)
    real(8), intent(in) :: dr
    integer, intent(in) :: n_b_max
    integer, intent(out) :: hist(n_b_max)
    real(8), intent(out) :: bins(n_b_max+1)
```

By the way, using `real(8)` is not a portable way how to specify 64-bit precision and will fail with certain compilers. Even good old `double precision` is better as it will always compile to something and often to 64 bit.

Comment: Would a large enough assumed-shape argument work, also?  And should there also be a "returned size" argument so the caller knows how much of the array is valid (depends on use case, I'm sure)?  [Asking in ignorance of things more than anything.]

Comment: Yes, assumed-shape would work too. You are also right about the returned size. Otherwise it would have to be inferred from the values of `bins` (they could be initialized to a negative number, or something.

Comment: @VladimirF do you know of some fortran library/subroutine that can build 2d histograms. something similar to hist2d from numpy i.e. with user defined bins.

Answer (score 9):

There's a few valid options/work-rounds that you can use.

**1.** Probably the simplest would be to arrange for python to call the function `n_bins`, and then use the result from that to call (a slightly modified version of) the `create_hist` function with non-allocatable output arrays of the correct sizes.

i.e. in Python:

```
n_b = n_bins(a,dr) # don't need to pass n - inferred from a
bins,hist = create_hist(a,dr,n_b) # bins and hist are auto-allocated
```

with the Fortran interface to `create_hist` now defined as

```
subroutine create_hist(a, n, dr, n_b, bins, hist)
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real(8), intent(in) :: a(n)
    real(8), intent(in) :: dr
    integer, intent(in) :: n_b
    integer, intent(out) :: hist(n_b)
    real(8), intent(out) :: bins(n_b+1)

    ! code follows

! you also need to specify the function n_bins...
```

---

That only works in cases where you can call `n_bins` cheaply and from outside `create_hist`. I know of 2 methods for simulating allocatable arrays for cases where that doesn't apply (i.e. the code to work out the array sizes is expensive and can't easily be separated).

**2.** The first is to use module level allocatable arrays (described in the documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/python-usage.html#fortran-90-module-data)). This is essentially an allocatable global variable - you call your function, it saves the data into the global variable and then you access that from Python. The disadvantage is that it isn't thread-safe (i.e. it's bad if you call `create_hist` simultaneously in parallel)

```
module something
    real(8), allocatable :: bins(:)
    integer, allocatable :: hist(:)
contains
    subroutine create_hist(a,n,dr)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real(8), intent(in) :: a(n)
        real(8), intent(in) :: dr
        integer :: n_b

        n_b = n_bins(a,n,dr)

        allocate(bins(n_b+1))
        allocate(hist(n_b))
        ! code follows
    end subroutine
end module
```

The Python call then looks like

```
something.create_hist(a,n,dr)
bins = something.bins # or possible bins = copy.copy(something.bins)
hist = something.hist # or possible hist = copy.copy(something.hist)
```

**3.** The other way which I quite like is to only allocate the arrays within the function (i.e. do not pass them in/out as parameters). However, what you do pass is a Python callback function that is called at the end and saves the arrays. This is thread-safe (I believe).

The fortran code then looks something like

```
subroutine create_hist(a,n,dr,callback)
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real(8), intent(in) :: a(n)
    real(8), intent(in) :: dr
    external callable ! note: better to specify the type with an interface block (see http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#callbacks)
    integer :: n_b
    real(8), allocatable :: bins(:)
    integer, allocatable :: hist(:)

    n_b = n_bins(a,n,dr)

    allocate(bins(n_b+1))
    allocate(hist(n_b))
    ! code follows
    call callable(bins,hist,n_b)
end subroutine
```

unfortunately it's then slightly more involved. You need to create a signature file with the command `f2py -m fortran_module -h fortran_module.pyf my_fortran_file.f90` (this is to build a Python module called `fortran_module` - change the names as appropriate), and then modify the relevant lines of it to clarify the dimensions of the callback function:

```
python module create_hist__user__routines 
    interface create_hist_user_interface 
        subroutine callable(bins,hist,n_b) ! in :f:my_fortran_file.f90:stuff:create_hist:unknown_interface
            real(kind=8), dimension(n_b+1) :: bins
            integer, dimension(n_b) :: hist
            integer :: n_b
        end subroutine callable
    end interface create_hist_user_interface
end python module create_hist__user__routines
```

compile that with `f2py -c fortran_module.pyf my_fortran_file.f90`

and then a short Python wrapper (to give you an easy interface) that looks like

```
def create_hist(a,dr):
    class SaveArraysCallable(object):
        def __call__(self,bins,hist):
            self.bins = bins.copy()
            self.hist = hist.copy()

    f = SaveArrayCallable()
    fortran_module.create_hist(a,dr,f)
    return f.bins, f.hist
```

---

**Summary**

For many cases option 1 is probably the best. Otherwise option 2 or option 3. I prefer option 3 because there aren't multithreading pitfalls to avoid (but really this is a corner-case that you'll likely never see). Option 2 is easier to implement.

Comment: Is there any documentation for option 3? Did you test it? The `allocatable,dimension(n_b+1)` is clearly against Fortran rules but perhaps f2py allows it for its callback interfaces. However, `callable` has still implicit interface inside `create_hist`.

Comment: I have tested option 3 and it does work. It's a horrendous hack of my own invention so there's no documentation. I think you're right though - I should delete the "allocatable" in the specification (I'll edit the answer to do that).

Comment: "However, callable has still implicit interface inside create_hist" - yes, that's almost certainly true. I don't really know Fortran well enough to fix that, but I'd gratefully accept a suggestion (or edit) that does.

Comment: Right - to follow this up the proper way to specify the callback interface looks to be to use interface blocks, as described here http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#callbacks (which I'm sure Vladimir F already knows, but might be useful to someone else). Unfortunately f2py does seem to be smart enough to read it, so you still have to create and modify the pyf file

Comment: Yes, without the `allocatable` in the interface it should be better.